# Pandas dataframe creation issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following functions purpose is to load data. the CITY_DATA[city]
maps to a user defined city's corresponding .csv file.

However, I end up with an empty dataframe at all stages when I "print(df)". Not sure what is going on here.

```
def load_data(city, month, day):
    """
    Loads data for the specified city and filters by month and day if applicable.

    Args:
        (str) city - name of the city to analyze
        (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
        (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
    Returns:
        df - Pandas DataFrame containing city data filtered by month and day
    """
    print (CITY_DATA[city])
    df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[city])
    print (df)
    df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
    df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month
    df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name

    if month != 'all':
        months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june']
        month = months.index(month) + 1
        df = df[df['month'] == month]

    if day != 'all':
        df = df[df['day_of_week'] == day.title()]

    print (df)
    return df
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: when are you getting an empty df, only before the return statement or already at the beginning (after reading the CSV file) ?

Comment: after reading the csv file

Comment: Are you sure the file exists and has the content you expect? You could try `print(open(CITY_DATA[city]))` (or something similar) to see if Python can find and read the file correctly.